# How to run a node express service on a host name instead of ip:port

Tags: node.js, https

I have created a nodejs express service. When you make it live by running something like `nodemon server.js` then it runs on `your-ip:port-you-listened-on` (`app.listen(3000);`)

**How do I get me nodejs service to run on a host name though?** I need this for my certificate to work. For example, I want it to run on `https://test.mydomain.com`, so a call would be something like `https://test.mydomain.com/login`

Comment: I think you should look at something like nginx. https://medium.com/@utkarsh_verma/configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-nodejs-application-on-aws-ubuntu-16-04-server-872922e21d38

Answer (score 0):

You can't. URLs, network services, DNS, and TCP/IP don't work like that.

The service has to listen on a port, on a network interface.

A hostname is resolved to an IP address using DNS. That IP address relates to a network interface.

If the URL doesn't specify a port, then the default one for the scheme is used (443 in the cast of HTTP).

---

So you need to listen on port `433` of the network interface that `test.mydomain.com` resolves to.

Comment: But if you say you can't, how do you ever put a certificate on a service, because the service serving name has to be same as the certificate (and the certificate is not ip:port, it is a website name)

Comment: @PaulKruger — You can have a cert which is for multiple host names. http://apetec.com/support/generatesan-csr.htm

Comment: Or multiple SSL certs on one server: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you had installed apache web server on your system you can map your request to a specific endpoint (along with port) using the virtual host. 
Please follow the below link.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts